# Can I pass the name of a parameter as an argument?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

Let say I have a function `F` with two optional parameters `par1` and `par2`.

I want to write a new function:

```
def some_plot(parameter):
    array = []
    for n in range(100):
        array.append(F(parameter = n))
    # make some plot using array
```

And then I want to make some plot by calling `some_plot('par1')` (or `some_plot(par1)`) which both split errors.

Is it possible to pass the name of the parameter as an argument?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to do? I think we need a more complete example to understand and answer your problem.

Comment: You meant `F(par1=n)`? `loop_through` is the *caller*.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Your goal and implementation aren't clear, because you haven't posted the full attempt.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @abarnert I make the example more complex to show the purpose

Comment: @CristiFati It splits some number. I make the example more complex to show the purpose.

Comment: couldn't you use `**kwargs` for this?

Comment: Short answer: No, it's not possible (automatically anyway).

Comment: I think you misunderstood function calling and parameters concepts (considering just the question). But it smells like an *XY* problem. What exactly are you trying to solve? Your question indicates that you are digging in the wrong direction.

Comment: @CristiFati I have a ML algorithm (`RandomForestClassifier`) form scikit-learn package which have a bunch of parameters. I want to find a "sweet spot" for each one by plotting some graphs.

Comment: Ok, now that I see the marked answer, I know what you meant. For me, it wasn't so clear from the question . :)

Comment: @CristiFati I thought that such info is redundant. Whithout it, the question is well posted and its abstraction makes it more universal. (This is why I posted it in such way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by constructing a dictionary and passing it using the `**` syntax.

```
def loop_through(arg_name):
    for n in range(100):
        F(**{arg_name: n})
```

Answer (score 5):

Supposing that you pass the name of the argument as a string, you can use keyword argument expansion:

```
def loop_through(parameter):

    for n in range(100):
        kwargs = {parameter: n}
        F(**kwargs)
```